# May I call 2 constructors with different arguments in the another constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I need to call a constructor 2 times in the another constructor.
For example:

```
public class SpinnerUtilityAssociationComparison extends SpinnerUtilityBase {
    static String adminType = "Association";

    public SpinnerUtilityAssociationComparison() {
    }

    public SpinnerUtilityAssociationComparison(ArrayList sourceList, ArrayList asisList, 
            ArrayList targetList, ArrayList columnListSchema_1, ArrayList columnListSchema_2, 
            ArrayList columnListSchema_3, String foldername) throws Exception {
        this(sourceList, asisList, columnListSchema_1, columnListSchema_2, foldername, "Schema1_Schema2");
        this(asisList, targetList, columnListSchema_2, columnListSchema_3, foldername, "Schema1_Schema3");

        GenerateCompareReport(sourceList, asisList, targetList, str + "Spinner" + adminType + "Data_CompareReport.xls");
    }

    public SpinnerUtilityAssociationComparison(ArrayList sourceList, ArrayList asisList, 
            ArrayList columnListSchema_1, ArrayList columnListSchema_2, String foldername, 
            String packageName) throws Exception {

        // String str = foldername+"/Spinner" + adminType +"DataFiles/";
        String str1 = foldername + "/Spinner" + adminType + "DataFiles/Spinner" + adminType + "Data_" + packageName + "/";
        new File(str1).mkdirs();

        String unique1 = "Spinner" + adminType + "Data_Unique1.xls";
        String unique2 = "Spinner" + adminType + "Data_Unique2.xls";
        String delta = "Spinner" + adminType + "Data_Delta.xls";
        String match = "Spinner" + adminType + "Data_Match.xls";
        GenerateUniqueData_1(sourceList, asisList, columnListSchema_1, columnListSchema_2, str1 + unique1);

        GenerateUniqueData_2(sourceList, asisList, columnListSchema_1, columnListSchema_2, str1 + unique2);

        GenerateDeltaData(sourceList, asisList, str1 + delta);

        GenerateMatchData(sourceList, asisList, str1 + match);
    }
}
```

I have to call single constructor with different arguments.
In the eclipse this giving the error : Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor.
How i can achieve this?

Comment: I'm confused.  Where or what is `GenerateCompareReport`, `GenerateUniqueData_1` and `GenerateUniqueData_2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So how i can achieve this.

You can't, basically - not the way you're trying. Each constructor chains to exactly one other constructor, either in the same class or the direct superclass.

I suggest you create one "primary" constructor which does *all* the initialization you need, and then chain to it - potentially indirectly - from all the other constructors. If you're doing non-initialization work in your constructor, that's a design smell in itself, and you should revisit your design.

I also *strongly* recommend that you start following Java naming conventions.

Comment: +1 for "I also strongly recommend that you start following Java naming conventions."! ;) (And because it's a good answer of course.. :))

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has answered this: You can't call two constructors this way.  One to a customer, please.

I hate seeing default constructors that do nothing.  Either do something sensible in your default ctor or don't provide one.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. The compiler only accepts one constructor call, and it is the **very first** call in every constructor. In most cases, though, you don't see one, but the compiler adds it.

```
public class MyClass { // is effectively 'public class MyClass extends Object'
    private String value;

    public MyClass() { // default constructor. Is it empty? Then don't add one
         this("hello"); // constructor chaining is possible though. 
    }

    public MyClass(String value) { //
        super(); // can be omitted, for it is a super() call to constructor of Object
        this.value = value; 
    }        
}

public class WrongClass {
    public WrongClass() {
        System.out.println("hello");
        this("hello"); // even this is impossible. It's not the first thing in your constructor
    }

    public WrongClass(String s) {
        super(); // implicitely called
    }
}
```

However, calling two constructors in one constructor is not your main problem. It seems that you simply want to do a bunch of things with a bunch of (raw typed) `ArrayLists`. Why not simply make them methods? This is also semantically better, for you don't construct an object, but you *do* a few things with all these objects. It compiles and works if you simply call a method:

```
public SpinnerUtilityAssociationComparison(ArrayList sourceList, ArrayList asisList, 
        ArrayList targetList, ArrayList columnListSchema_1, ArrayList columnListSchema_2, 
        ArrayList columnListSchema_3, String foldername) throws Exception {
    doSomething(sourceList, asisList, columnListSchema_1, columnListSchema_2, foldername, "Schema1_Schema2");
    doSomething(asisList, targetList, columnListSchema_2, columnListSchema_3, foldername, "Schema1_Schema3");

    GenerateCompareReport(sourceList, asisList, targetList, str + "Spinner" + adminType + "Data_CompareReport.xls");
}

public doSomething(ArrayList sourceList, ArrayList asisList, 
        ArrayList columnListSchema_1, ArrayList columnListSchema_2, String foldername, 
        String packageName) throws Exception {
    /* do something with all those lists */
}
```

Then again, you shouldn't use constructors to do things. You use them to construct your objects, set and initialize some values, and then calling methods on these objects to actually do things.

```
SpinnerUtilityAssociationComparison utilObject = new SpinnerUtilityAssociationComparison();
doSomething(sourceList, asisList, columnListSchema_1, columnListSchema_2, foldername, "Schema1_Schema2");
```